# Way to connect to a vpn tunnel which connects another openvpn

Tags: linux, ssh, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to work on company's VPN (`VPN-C`), but from the specific Internet connection of my home, `VPN-C` cannot be accessed, yet another `VPN-B` could be connected from my home. I'm sure that `VPN-B` will always be able to connect to `VPN-c`, so I'm wondering whether there's a way to connect to `VPN-B` (which is a linux server machine I could ssh to), and send all data via `VPN-C`, in which way, `VPN-B` will be transparent and I will acting as connecting directly via `VPN-C`. Any suggestions?

Comment: If the company has IT support then the question is off-topic (issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are) and you should ask them to help you. On the other hand the company may be "Billy Bo and his brother-in-law" without IT guy and then the question is on-topic (but it's my opinion only). There *may* be a reason why `VPN-C` cannot be accessed from your home. Or maybe it can be reconfigured and made accessible? I think the general answer to your question is: yes, there is a way. But you gave us little information – what kind of VPN? your OS? any specific software? etc.

Comment: Either this is a problem with your ISP, or your company has blacklisted (or not whitelisted) your address and you should make a formal request an not try to bypass security controls?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can layer VPNs. Just make sure your routing tables are correct: After establishing the first (outer) VPN, set a /32 route on the tun/tap of this VPN to the server of the second (inner) VPN (if the IP address of the inner VPN is not fixed, you may need a `host` lookup first). In this way, when you establish the inner VPN, the other VPN will still work, even though the `default` route is now replaced.

Comment: do you have any posts or articles could walk me step by step? I'm not quite familiar with network engineering. Thanks man~